# Can “clean off/out/up” sometimes be used interchangeably?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-difference

I know that **clean off**, **clean out**, and **clean up** are different, but I think sometimes they can be used interchangeably because they share the meaning of *clean*.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think so. Provide us with an example, please.

Comment: To this US English speaker, *clean off* = remove things from the top of something, *clean out* = remove garbage from inside of something, and *clean up* = make clean in general.  But it really depends on context too.